# Assign functions between modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a module where I want to assign a function to a public variable and then use the function inside that module. See the example below for what I thought I would be able to do.

**main.js**

```
;(function() {
    const test = require("./test");

    function newFunction() {
        console.log("New function");
    }

    // This works fine
    test.someFunction = newFunction;
    test.someFunction();

    // But this doesn't
    test.callSomeFunction();
}());
```

**test.js**

```
;(function() {
    let someFunction = function() {
        console.log("Old function");
    }

    function callSomeFunction() {
        someFunction();
    }

    module.exports = {
        someFunction,
        callSomeFunction
    }
}());
```

To make this work, I currently have a method to set the function in the module, so `test.js` would look like the snippet below.

**test.js**

```
;(function() {
    let someFunction = function() {
        console.log("Old function");
    }

    function callSomeFunction() {
        someFunction();
    }

    function setSomeFunction(newFunction) {
        someFunction = newFunction;
    }

    module.exports = {
        setSomeFunction,
        callSomeFunction
    }
}());
```

Since I don't feel that this is a very elegant solution, I was wondering if there was an alternative, maybe some way to get the first two snippets to work as inteded, or if I'm stuck with the setter method.

Answer (score 0):

```
function callSomeFunction() {
    someFunction();
}
```

`callSomeFunction` is defined earlier in time than `someFunction` (known as [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)).

Resulting in the following definition order:

```
1. callSomeFunction
2. someFunction
```

You should either change this function to be stored by a `const` or `let` like you did with `someFunction` or have them both as `function`.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your solution unfortunately doesn't work. Even when defining both functions either with `let` or `function`, the same behaviour occurs, where the old function is called.